Microsoft custom teams app is closing if user changed the teams tabs
I have created Microsoft teams custom app and opened it. I received a message in original teams. I read that message by clicking chat button in teams. This time, my custom app was not active. I need to again click my custom teams app button to open the app. Is it possible to make the custom app active even if the user changed the teams tabs?

Hello @sajithhhhh- Microsoft Teams currently does not allow a custom app to remain active when a user switches to another tab.

Microsoft Teams currently does not allow a custom app to remain active when a user switches to another tab.
